# Airflow : Run a task when some upstream is skipped by shortcircuit

Tags: airflow

I have a task that I'll call `final` that has multiple upstream connections. When one of the upstreams gets skipped by `ShortCircuitOperator` this task gets skipped as well. I don't want `final` task to get skipped as it has to report on DAG success.

To avoid it getting skipped I used `trigger_rule='all_done'`, but it still gets skipped.

If I use `BranchPythonOperator` instead of `ShortCircuitOperator` `final` task doesn't get skipped. It would seem like branching workflow could be a solution, even though not optimal, but now `final` will not respect failures of upstream tasks.

How do I get it to only run when upstreams are successful or skipped?

Sample ShortCircuit DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import ShortCircuitOperator
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 8, 1)}

dag = DAG(
    'shortcircuit_test',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
    catchup=False)

def shortcircuit_fn():
    return randint(0, 1) == 1

task_1 = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_1')
task_2 = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_2')

work = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='work')
short = ShortCircuitOperator(dag=dag, task_id='short_circuit', python_callable=shortcircuit_fn)
final = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id="final", trigger_rule="all_done")

task_1 >> short >> work >> final
task_1 >> task_2 >> final
```

[image: DAG with shortcircuit operator]

Sample Branch DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 8, 1)}

dag = DAG(
    'branch_test',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
    catchup=False)

# these two are only here to protect tasks from getting skipped as direct dependencies of branch operator
to_do_work = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='to_do_work')
to_skip_work = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='to_skip_work')

def branch_fn():
    return to_do_work.task_id if randint(0, 1) == 1 else to_skip_work.task_id

task_1 = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_1')
task_2 = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_2')

work = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='work')
branch = BranchPythonOperator(dag=dag, task_id='branch', python_callable=branch_fn)
final = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id="final", trigger_rule="all_done")

task_1 >> branch >> to_do_work >> work >> final
branch >> to_skip_work >> final
task_1 >> task_2 >> final
```

[image: DAG with branch operator]

Answer (score 16):

I've ended up with developing custom ShortCircuitOperator based on the original one:

```py
class ShortCircuitOperator(PythonOperator, SkipMixin):
    """
    Allows a workflow to continue only if a condition is met. Otherwise, the
    workflow "short-circuits" and downstream tasks that only rely on this operator
    are skipped.

    The ShortCircuitOperator is derived from the PythonOperator. It evaluates a
    condition and short-circuits the workflow if the condition is False. Any
    downstream tasks that only rely on this operator are marked with a state of "skipped".
    If the condition is True, downstream tasks proceed as normal.

    The condition is determined by the result of `python_callable`.
    """

    def find_tasks_to_skip(self, task, found_tasks=None):
        if not found_tasks:
            found_tasks = []
        direct_relatives = task.get_direct_relatives(upstream=False)
        for t in direct_relatives:
            if len(t.upstream_task_ids) == 1:
                found_tasks.append(t)
                self.find_tasks_to_skip(t, found_tasks)
        return found_tasks

    def execute(self, context):
        condition = super(ShortCircuitOperator, self).execute(context)
        self.log.info("Condition result is %s", condition)

        if condition:
            self.log.info('Proceeding with downstream tasks...')
            return

        self.log.info(
            'Skipping downstream tasks that only rely on this path...')

        tasks_to_skip = self.find_tasks_to_skip(context['task'])
        self.log.debug("Tasks to skip: %s", tasks_to_skip)

        if tasks_to_skip:
            self.skip(context['dag_run'], context['ti'].execution_date,
                      tasks_to_skip)

        self.log.info("Done.")
```

This operator makes sure no downstream task that rely on multiple paths are getting skipped because of one skipped task.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. It appears that the built-in ShortCircuit operator skips ALL downstream tasks without checking, for example, for trigger rules or other considerations.

Comment: Nice , It helped me to build a more stronger solution.

Since we could have a downstream task with more than 1 upstream skipped tasks , your solution will not skip this task  even if this task have all his upstream skipped by your shortcircuitOperator

Comment: You should make a PR to Airflow, this should be the default short circuit operator.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm using Airflow 2.x I have the problem with

`
self.skip(context['dag_run'], context['ti'].execution_date, tasks_to_skip)
`

It doesn't solve the issue and skips the whole branch, including tasks which have other up-streams. Even I pass only one task to `tasks_to_skip`.

For example I have the following

t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> (t4, t5)
|
t4 >> t6 >> t7
|
t5 >> t7
|
t7 >> t8 >> t9

t3 -- operator which skip one of downstream, skips only one t4 or t5
when t4 or t5 is skipped, all further tasks also skipped, including t7, t8, t9

PS: | - new line

Comment: to everyone in 2023 see the answer below about using `ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False`

Comment: bro re-wrote airflow built-ins cuz Apache couldn't get it right, Sigma skills!

Answer (score 10):

I'm posting another possible workaround for this since this is a method that does not require a custom operator implementation.

I was influenced by the solution in this blog using a PythonOperator which raises an AirflowSkipException which skips the task itself and then downstream tasks individually.

https://godatadriven.com/blog/the-zen-of-python-and-apache-airflow/

This then respects the trigger_rule of the final downstream task, which in my case I set to `trigger_rule='none_failed'`.

Modfied example as per the blog to include a final task:

```
def fn_short_circuit(**context):
    if <<<some condition>>>:
        raise AirflowSkipException("Skip this task and individual downstream tasks while respecting trigger rules.")

check_date = PythonOperator(
    task_id="check_if_min_date",
    python_callable=_check_date,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

task1 = DummyOperator(task_id="task1", dag=dag)
task2 = DummyOperator(task_id="task2", dag=dag)
work = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='work')
short = ShortCircuitOperator(dag=dag, task_id='short_circuit', python_callable=fn_short_circuit
final_task = DummyOperator(task_id="final_task",
    trigger_rule='none_failed',
    dag=dag)


task_1 >> short >> work >> final_task
task_1 >> task_2 >> final_task
```

Comment: Also one thing to note, this applies to all followings tasks that are downstream; eg: `task_1 >> task_2 >> final_task >> final_final_task`. By adding `trigger_rule='none_failed'`, you also enable `final_final_task`. Might be obvious, but I was hesitant it would work at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

**This question is still legit with airflow 1.10.X**

---

**The following solution work with airflow 1.10.X , not tested yet with airflow 2.X**

ShortCircuitOperator will skip all downstream TASK whatever the trigger_rule set

---

The solution of @michael-spector will only work with simple case and not this case :

[image: airflow dag exemple]

with @michael-spector the task **L** will not be skipped ( only **E , F , G , H** tasks will be skipped )

A solution is this (based on @michael-spector proposition) :

```py
class ShortCircuitOperatorOnlyDirectDownStream(PythonOperator, SkipMixin):
"""
Work like a ShortCircuitOperator but it will only skip the task that have in their upstream this task

So if a task have this task in his upstream AND another task it will not be skipped

        -> B -> C -> D ------\
      /                       \
A -> K                         -> Y
 \                            /
   -> F -> G - P -----------/


If K is a normal ShortCircuitOperator and condition is False then B , C , D and Y will be skip

if K is ShortCircuitOperatorOnlyDirectDownStream and condition is False then B , C , D will be skip , but not Y


found_tasks_name contains the names of the previous skipped task
found_tasks contains the airflow_task_id of the previous skipped task

:return found_tasks
"""

def find_tasks_to_skip(self, task, found_tasks_to_skip=None, found_tasks_to_skip_names=None):
    if not found_tasks_to_skip:  # list of task_id to skip
        found_tasks_to_skip = []

    # necessary because found_tasks do not keep a copy of names but airflow task_id
    if not found_tasks_to_skip_names:
        found_tasks_to_skip_names = set()

    direct_relatives = task.get_direct_relatives(upstream=False)
    for t in direct_relatives:
        self.log.info("UPSTREAM : " + str(t.upstream_task_ids))
        self.log.info(
            " Does all skipped task " +
            str(found_tasks_to_skip_names) +
            " contain the upstream tasks" +
            str(t.upstream_task_ids)
        )

        # if len == 1 then the task is only precede by a skipped task
        # otherwise check if ALL upstream task are skipped
        if len(t.upstream_task_ids) == 1 or all(elem in found_tasks_to_skip_names for elem in t.upstream_task_ids):
            found_tasks_to_skip.append(t)
            found_tasks_to_skip_names.add(t.task_id)
            self.find_tasks_to_skip(t, found_tasks_to_skip, found_tasks_to_skip_names)

    return found_tasks_to_skip

def execute(self, context):
    condition = super(ShortCircuitOperatorOnlyDirectDownStream, self).execute(context)
    self.log.info("Condition result is %s", condition)

    if condition:
        self.log.info('Proceeding with downstream tasks...')
        return

    self.log.info(
        'Skipping downstream tasks that only rely on this path...')

    tasks_to_skip = self.find_tasks_to_skip(context['task'])
    self.log.debug("Tasks to skip: %s", tasks_to_skip)

    if tasks_to_skip:
        self.skip(context['dag_run'], context['ti'].execution_date,
                  tasks_to_skip)

    self.log.info("Done.")
```

Comment: Can you also post how to use this operator?

Answer (score 2):

The `ShortCircuitOperator` can now be configured to respect downstream task. Default behavior is not respecting it. You can make the operator repsect by setting `ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False`.

```py
task = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='task_id',
    python_callable=function,
    ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work by making `final` task to check for statuses of upstream instances. Not beautiful as only way to access their state I've found was by querying Airflow DB.

```py
# # additional imports to ones in question code
# from airflow import AirflowException
# from airflow.models import TaskInstance
# from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
# from airflow.settings import Session
# from airflow.utils.state import State
# from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

def all_upstreams_either_succeeded_or_skipped(dag, task, task_instance, **context):
    """
    find directly upstream task instances and count how many are not in prefered statuses.
    return True if we got no instances with non-preferred statuses.
    """
    upstream_task_ids = [t.task_id for t in task.get_direct_relatives(upstream=True)]
    session = Session()
    query = (session
        .query(TaskInstance)
        .filter(
            TaskInstance.dag_id == dag.dag_id,
            TaskInstance.execution_date.in_([task_instance.execution_date]),
            TaskInstance.task_id.in_(upstream_task_ids)
        )
    )
    upstream_task_instances = query.all()
    unhappy_task_instances = [ti for ti in upstream_task_instances if ti.state not in [State.SUCCESS, State.SKIPPED]]
    print(unhappy_task_instances)
    return len(unhappy_task_instances) == 0

def final_fn(**context):
    """
    fail if upstream task instances have unwanted statuses
    """
    if not all_upstreams_either_succeeded_or_skipped(**context):
        raise AirflowException("Not all upstream tasks succeeded.")
    # Do things

# will run when upstream task instances are done, including failed
final = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="final",
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
    python_callable=final_fn,
    provide_context=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

This may have been added *after* you asked your initial question, but Airflow now conveniently has a trigger_rule value of `none_failed`. If you set this on your final task, it should complete whether upstream tasks are skipped or succeeded, just not when they fail.

More info: https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules

Comment: Unfortunately this will have NO EFFECT with a shortcircuit

because the task "final" will be already skip, so the trigger_rule is not evaluated by airflow.

So it do not work !