# Structuring Airflow DAG with complex trigger rules

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

This is probably as much a logic problem as anything, but it has me stumped. I have the following dag:
[image]

I have two main branching events that are tripping me up:

- Following A, only the branch B or C should run.
- Following B, D should optionally run before E.

Right now I have this implemented so that E has the trigger rule "none_failed", which was needed to prevent E from being skipped when D is skipped. This set up works for all cases except when C needs to run. In this case, C and E run simultaneously (you can see via the box colors B/D are skipped as intended, but E is green). After reading the trigger rule docs, I understand *why* this is happening (both E's parent tasks are skipped, therefore it runs). However I can't seem to figure out how to get the intended behavior out of this (e.g. keep the current behavior of B/D/E when that branch is run but *don't* run E when C is run).

For additional context, this is not my entire DAG. Tasks C and E converge into another task downstream of these with a trigger rule of ONE_FAILED, but I omitted this from the example for simplicity. Any ideas how to get the intended behavior?

Comment: E should not run when B or D failed?

Comment: That is correct, E should not run when 1. B is skipped, or 2. B or D fails.

Comment: In that case, doesn't default's "all_success" for E do what you are looking for?

Comment: No, in that case E will not run when D is skipped. "none_failed" for E is more correct than "all_done" in the sense that E it won't run when B or D fails, but still doesn't address the problem of E running when C is run due to the way skipping isn't cascaded through rules other than "all_success" or "all_failed".

Comment: I updated the original post to specify "none_failed" instead of "all_done" since  that is more correct but still not the original issue.

Comment: What operator is B?  and D?

Comment: B is a BranchPythonOperator. D is a custom operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution but seems it covers all of your scenarios. Main thing is that I added a dummy task before E in order to control E's timing and change `trigger_rule` for E to be "one_success".

"one_success" requires at least 1 immediate parent to be succeeded, so for E, either D or dummy has to success in order for E to run.

```
A = BranchPythonOperator(task_id='A', python_callable=_branch_A, dag=dag)

B = BranchPythonOperator(task_id='B', python_callable=_branch_B, dag=dag)
C = DummyOperator(task_id='C', dag=dag)

D = PythonOperator(task_id='D', python_callable=_test, dag=dag)
dummy = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy', dag=dag)
E = DummyOperator(task_id='E', trigger_rule='one_success', dag=dag)

A >> [B, C]
B >> [D, dummy] >> E
```

Demo

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: let me know if I miss any scenarios.

Comment: This looks good and works for the intended use case. I was considering using a ShortCircuitOperator with "none_failed" between D and E that checked the status of B, which would have the same result, but feels more complex. I like your solution better, though I wish Airflow didn't require workarounds like this.

Comment: I was thinking about ShortCircuit as well but in your case, I couldn't think to make it work with ShortCircuit since you have A >> C without any of B-E cases.  Anyhow, this was a similar case but not cover A >> C scenario and also complex.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725746/airflow-run-a-task-when-some-upstream-is-skipped-by-shortcircuit